# Why is this variable both empty and not empty according to the class state's logic?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple page with a form. THe user writes into the input and hits submit. At this point the handleSubmit function sets the state of the class variable as whatever the user inputs.

However the next line, when console logging this variable, shows an empty String.

The other weird issue is that once a user has submitted a line of text and thus it was supposedly set as the class variable, my program checks for the existence of text in this variable. If it is an empty String, then the form should load as usual, but if the String is not empty (i.e the variable has had text saved onto it) then a  should appear with the variable's text. My pprogram must somehow see that the variable is not empty yet instead of displaying the String, it displays an empty String i.e nothing is displayed.

How can this be? How can a variable be both not empty but also empty?

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';


class Storyboard extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            topField: ''
     
        }


        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)

    }

    handleInputChange = (event) => {
        console.log('Text entered: ', event.target.value)

    }


    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            // [name]: value
            topField : value
        })
        console.log('topField: ' , this.state.topField)
        alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.topField);
        event.preventDefault();
        
    }




    render() {
        if (this.state.topField === ''){

            return (
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                    <input type="text"  onChange={this.handleInputChange} name="topField"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            )
        }
        else return (
            <a href={'/'} >{this.state.topField} </a>
        )
```

User starts typing:
[image: step one]
User clicks submit, console log of variable 'topField' is empty despite its state being set:
[image: step two]
Submit button pressed, the page is reloaded with an empty String despite it not being empty by the 'if' statement of the code:
[image: step three]

**After edit: Undefined result for variable - why is this?**
[image: edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem of console.log(), setState is an asynchronous call so use it like:

```
this.setState({
        // [name]: value
        topField : value
    },()=>{
    console.log('topField: ' , this.state.topField)
     alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.topField);
    })
```

Comment: Ok thank you that's good to know. But then why is <a href={'/'} >{this.state.topField} </a> showing up an empty string, yet the if condition to generate that part is finding that the string is not empty?

Comment: Also, I have just edited it to account for the asynchronus state (as per your comment above)  and the console .log is reading 'undefined' for the variable's value - why would this be?

Comment: <a href={'/'} >{this.state.topField} </a>  returns empty string because <a > tag in react refreshes your entire index.html which in turn clears your app data so, to overcome this problem use <Link to ="/">{this.state.topField}</Link> and import Link from react-router-dom

Answer (score 1):

setState is an asynchronous function.

You should have a look on the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous